# React setState hook async updating issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update some content on the screen upon a change in the data. I'm using React function component with hooks. When the data is updated in the parent element, I send it via props to `PlayerControls`:

```
export const PlayerControls = (props) => {
....

  const [heatmaps, setHeatMaps] = React.useState("");
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  useEffect(fetchData, [props.videoData]);
  useEffect(updateHeatmaps, [data]);

  function fetchData () {
     d3.csv(require(`./data/${props.videoData}`)).then((d) => setData(d));
  }

  function updateHeatmaps(){
        if (data && data.length) {
            const temp = data.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <Heatmap size={[400, 50]} data={item} key={index}/>
                )
            });
        setHeatMaps(temp);
        }
   }

   return (
       <div>
         {heatmaps}
       </div>
   );

}
```

The problem is, although this works properly for the initial data, it does not update `heatmaps` on the screen. Now, I'm familiar with the fact that `setState` hook is asynchronous and there are solutions (such as using the `useEffect` hook to update the state and add the state as a dependency), e.g., [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately). The problem is I'm updating the state withing another function and I cannot use `useEffect` there or in the return function. I would really appreciate any solutions, this problem has been dragging me along for a while now, makes me wonder if these hooks and function components are a solution for all the use cases or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as @CertainPerformance mentioned in the comments above, the problem was not with the `useState` hooks, but it was from within the `updateHeatmap` function. Apparently, when using `.map` function, your keys should be globally unique. I used `index` as the key, and since this index did not change after the update, **React** didn't detect a change and did not update the `heatmaps` state.

Changing

```
const temp = data.map((item, index) => {
     return (
             <Heatmap size={[400, 50]} data={item} key={index}/>
            )
     });
```

to

```
const temp = data.map((item, index) => {
     let key = props.videoData + '.' + index;
     return (
             <Heatmap size={[400, 50]} data={item} key={key}/>
            )
     });
```

fixed my problem. I hope this helps other people facing similar issues!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rendering the `heatmaps` string, return the mapped data if it exists when rendering:

```
export const PlayerControls = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
    useEffect(fetchData, [props.videoData]);

    function fetchData() {
        d3.csv(require(`./data/${props.videoData}`)).then((setData);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {data?.map((item, index) => (
                <Heatmap size={[400, 50]} data={item} key={index} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Example snippet:

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
const getData = () => Promise.resolve(['foo', 'bar']);
const PlayerControls = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
    React.useEffect(fetchData, [props.videoData]);

    function fetchData() {
        getData().then(setData);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {data && data.map((item, index) => (
                <Heatmap size={[400, 50]} data={item} key={index} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
const Heatmap = ({ data }) => <div>{data}</div>;
ReactDOM.render(<PlayerControls />, document.querySelector('.react'));
</script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

Comment: I was really excited about your answer, but it doesn't work. My guess is that your solution doesn't detect that the data has changed?

Comment: Oh, the `updateHeatmaps` isn't used anymore, so it can be completely removed. Was probably throwing a ReferenceError before

Comment: Yeah, I get you, but it still doesn't work and my guess is that somehow, nothing triggers the change in the data. (to be more specific, when I say it does not work, I mean it doesn't show the change in your solution, similar to my solution) -- although, your solution still works for the initial data. :(

Comment: Any console errors? Are you sure the `.then` is running? (As always, it's good to add a `.catch` to Promises to check if they reject) Is `setData` called with an array?

Comment: Yes, I print "d" inside `then` function and it shows the updated data. But of course, it does not update the "data" through `setData` because useState hooks are async. That's why I guess the problem still exists with your code because react does get notified when `data` is being updated.

Comment: I made an example snippet with a dummy Promise. It looks to work as desired - press "Run code snippet" to see `foo` and `bar` being rendered. If it doesn't work on your end, it sounds like the problem is outside of the code posted in the question

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yes, apparently, there was a silly mistake somewhere and I'm going to post it as the answer. But your code is a good substitute and I really liked it in general! I'm upvoting your answer :)